# How to install R-Linux?

Tags: software-installation

I don't know how to install the software as follows: [R-Linux](https://www.r-studio.com/free-linux-recovery/Download.shtml). I need this program to recover lost information. The directions are: 'Download the archive file with extension .db'.

Comment: What is "R-linux"? Is there a link to a website?

Comment: @user68186 I suspect that -r-base is a different application to R-Linux?

Comment: @mikewhatever I have added in a link for the OP...

Comment: @andrew.46 I got confused between RStudio which is a frontend of R, and what you pointed to R-Studio.

Answer (score 3):

I installed R-Linux quite easily on 64bit Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver and the following directions should allow you to do the same. Open a Terminal window and run the following two commands:

```
wget https://www.r-studio.com/downloads/RLinux5_x64.deb
sudo dpkg -i RLinux5_x64.deb
```

This was enough to download and install this application and I attach a gratuitous screenshot showing R-Linux running on my own system:

[image]

Should be easy enough to duplicate on your own system? BTW how cool is the command line :)

Comment: Appreciate for your detailed answer. Link which I tried to use is: https://www.r-studio.com/free-linux-recovery/Download.shtml
What should I run in the terminal window? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Appreciate for your detailed answer. It works. Thanks so much.You are so helpful I appreciate that.

Comment: @ZlatinStamatov Great to hear that it all worked out! If you are completely happy with my answer you can 'Accept' it by clicking on the Check or tick box to the left of the answer...